# Error in new.env(parent = environment(train_fun)) :

Tags: r, ggmap

I want to use ggmap to plot the city of the U.S today and this error

> Error in new.env(parent = environment(train_fun)) :    use of NULL
>   environment is defunct

is produced after I input

```
us <- c(left = -125, bottom = 25.75, right = -67, top = 49) 
map <-get_stamenmap(us, zoom = 5, maptype = "toner-lite") 
ggmap(map)
```

How could I fix this problem? Thx.

Comment: Cannot replicate error. Try restarting your r-session and run the code clean.

Comment: Works on my Mac just fine. You should make sure all you packages and dependencies are up-to-date.

Comment: Yes I am sure all me packages have been updated to the newest version as I have tried several times repeatedly before. Actually I do not know what this error means?